# Invoke a method of an object of type Class

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I ll try to set it as simple as possible because it confuses me too.

I got a method returning an object of type `Class` i.e.

```
public Class foo(){...}
```

When I call this method I'm keeping the result in a variable of type Class i.e.

```
Class obj = new foo();
```

`foo()` can return many different classes BUT all of them contain the same method `bar()`.

How can I invoke that method from my `obj` variable?

I tried `obj.bar()` but the IDE doesn't seem to like it. I get

> Error:(59, 34) error: cannot find symbol method `bar()`

Comment: `Class obj = new foo()` is never going to be valid, unless you're talking about a different `Class` type than `java.lang.Class`. A short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem would make all this a lot clearer.

Comment: You have to use `((foof)obj).bar() `

Comment: As said by Jon Skeet, `Class obj = new foo()` isn't valid. You maybe want to do something like `Foo obj = foo().newInstance()`, and then `obj.bar()`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to group behaviors, that's what [Java interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) do:

```
interface Barer {
    String bar();
}

class Foo implements Barer {
    String bar() {
        return "I'm a Foo";
    }
}

class Fooz implements Barer {
    String bar() {
        return "I'm a Fooz";
    }
}
```

Then in you code you can have something like:

```
Barer obj;

if (something) {
    obj = new Foo();
} else {
    obj = new Fooz();
}

obj.bar()
```

It makes little sense in fact to store the return value of a constructor in a `Class` object.

---

If you really are in the case that you need a Class object (remember that it will just point to the Class, not to the instance you have created), you can use [Java reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html):

```
Class obj = new foo();
Method method = obj.getDeclaredMethod("bar");
method.invoke(null);
```

Comment: That's probably the best way to do. If for any reason one have to go to the ugly hacking technique (but probably one should adapt its code not to do so, and use interface described above instead) :       Method m = obj.getDeclaredMethod("bar", null);
      Object o = m.invoke(null, null);

Comment: yep, I just added that case ;)

Comment: You're faster than me :) . Also, as noticed in question's comments, `Class obj = new foo();` should be replaced by `Class obj = foo();`

Answer (score 1):

if method foo() returns Class, it means it don't return actual instance of the objet on which you want to call bar() method, but the class itself, so it's not possible to call method bar() on Class as Class.class don't have a method bar.

In your code example there is some mistake

```
Class obj = new foo();
```

The keyword **new** mean you're creating a new instance of a class, not you're calling a method on an object.

---

In fact the right approach would be to use interfaces.

Instead of returning Class from foo method, declare an interface,

```
public interface MyInterface {
  public void bar();
}
```

and make foo() returning MyInterface instead of Class.

Then you can do

```
MyInterface obj = tmp.foo();
obj.bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

If all returned values are objects of classes that implements the same method, you should declare that method in separate interface and let them implement it. Later on you can use generic wildcard like `<? extends BarInterface>` or change return type to `BarInterface`.

```
public interface BarInterface{
    public void bar();
}
```

and

```
public <T extends BarInterface> foo(){...}
```

or

```
public BarInterface foo() {...}
```